# Using AWS IoT and Mosquitto client causes a TLS error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, mqtt, iot, mosquitto

I am new to AWS IoT. I am following the example in the link below about setting up JITP (Just In Time Provisioning). Everything goes fine such as registering the Root CA, private key verification certificate etc.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/iot/setting-up-just-in-time-provisioning-with-aws-iot-core/

I don't normally post "what is wrong with my code" kind of questions, but i'm out of ideas with this one. When I try the last step to use the MQTT Mosquitto client to connect and publish to AWS IoT Core with the below command

```
mosquitto_pub --cafile root.cert --cert deviceCertAndCACert.crt --key deviceJITPCert.key -h a9bqki6ij1hx9.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com -p 8883 -q 1 -t foo/bar -I anyclientID --tls-version tlsv1.2 -m "Hello" -d
```

I get the error :

```
Client anyclientID4406 sending CONNECT
Error: A TLS error occurred.
```

I can't understand whatsoever what is the problem here with the handshake. All the keys and certificates are generated correctly. I have tried it from the start time and time again. Perhaps i'm missing one obvious step. If anyone with some experience might know what is going wrong i'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If you can use a 1.5.x version of mosquitto_pub you should get better TLS error information.

Comment: Does the corresponding policy allow the client to connect and publish to the topic?

Comment: @blt Yes, it does

Comment: Does it connect on the second try?

The thing and policy will be created as part of the JITP process. I find that the first connect will fail with AWS IoT terminating the TLS session. However, the thing, policy and certificate are registered and subsequent connects succeed.